# How do i declare multiple items in a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, declare

alright, So I'm working on a small python Command-line calculator,

this was just a test:

```
import time

calc = print("\n what calculation do you want to use\n")

time.sleep(1)

menu = print(" MENU:\n **********\n mult for multiplication\n add for addition\n sub for substraction\n div for divide\n **********")

time.sleep(1)

ask = input(" what calculation do you want to use from the menu? \n")

much = input(" how many numbers do you calculate? (5 maximumn & 2 minimum) \n")

if(much == " 2" or much == "2" and ask == " mult" or ask == "mult"):
    num1_2 = input(" First Number? ")
    num2_2 = input("\n Second Number? ")
    answer_2 = print(int(num1_2) * int(num2_2))


time.sleep(11)
```

and it was working correctly, i was planning to complete all the `if:` and the `elif:` statements,
but then i thought that i could make my code more efficient,  so i thought i can use a `for` loop
like this:

```
for value in range(int(much)):
    output = input("Number? ")

print(int(value) * int(value))
```

**note: (much) is the the variable name that i used for declaring how many numbers does the user wants to calculate**

so, when i used the for loop it showed a wrong answer, for example when i multiplied 2 by 2 the answer was 1.

so how can i declare multiple items in the `for` loop to multiplie the first user input by the second one?

this is confusing because the number of outputs is not stable.

Comment: Append them to a list.

Comment: You have it printing *value x value*, where *value* is the last index (if much is 2, then value is 1), not the number the user input.

Comment: so i should multiplie what by what?

Comment: I would try output = 1 before the for loop, and output *= input(“Number”) inside the loop. Then print output.

Comment: i tried but when i run the program and i type 2 times 2 the program closes and does not print anything

Comment: I should have written output *= int(input(“Number”)), since input returns a string. The answer by @redmicelles below works, right?

Comment: yes thank you, and yes The answer by @redmicelles`is`working.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do know that, the `for` loop remembers only the value of the last iteration. You may have a variable(Not necessarily a list) outside of store the values of your iteration result. For example:

```
result = 1
for value in range(int(much)):
    output = input("Number? ")
    result*=int(output)
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes that worked but i didn't quite understand what do you mean by (You may have a variable(Not necessarily a list) outside of store the values of your iteration result)?

Comment: I think @redmicelles was saying that you can use an int or float (such as *result* in the example given), instead of a list as suggested by alaniwi, to store the intermediate and final computations.